# Options for reducing transaction log size when disk space is restricted

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, disk-space, standard-edition

I have a very unfortunate situation in which I have some SQL Server (standard edition) databases living on a small (~120gb) disk, and a transaction log which has grown to 50gb+. Unfortunately, the backup disk is only 45gb. The data itself is across all databases is only ~20gb.

I need to reduce the size of the transaction log to prevent the disk filling up, but I'm unable to back it up because it's too big, and I'm unable to get even temporary space from the server vendor. I've taken a full backup of the data and transferred that out to another machine,

**What are my options for reducing the transaction log size?**

Comment: Switch to simple recovery, run two checkpoints, then run dbcc shrinkfile against the log, then switch back to full and turn on log backups so this doesn't happen again. Well, it will, so in the meantime find a host that has disks that can scale with you and, more importantly, be more than useless when you have an emergency.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Aaron. I had tried to switch to simple before but the operation failed saying I needed to wait for a backup to complete (I hadn't realised one was running in the background). We'll be dumping the host when we end-of-life the product :D